# Best VPS Service in Europe?

Tags: vps, service

I know we've had a lot of "Who's your favourite VPS provider?" type questions, but most of the top providers reside in the USA (Linode and Slicehost) come to mind. What about providers that aren't 1,500 miles away.

What European VPS service would you recommend which has a similar price point to those seen at linode/slicehost?

[Edit] Per the comments below : It was more of a general question, but I'm looking for a provider that can host and run a forum (phpBB3 or something similar) and a custom content management system that will handle a file exchange. About 50 to 100 users can be on the server at any one time. It's for a niche market so I don't expect those numbers to grow. The files are text based and can be compressed, so for space, anything from 10GB + is a good start. I'm not sure on memory, but I'll be planning to run NGinx with PHP-FPM and mySQL.

Comment: "Best" too subjective to get good answers without more details. What sort of resources are you talking about needing/wanting and what you plan to do with them?

Comment: i know it does not directly answer your question - but consider rps from ovh - you'll get 'own' cpu / memory and just shared storage. they are quite affordabe: http://www.ovh.co.uk/products/rps_offers.xml

Comment: i know you asked this over six months ago but linode are now offering london based vps and slicehost are rumored to be offering the same early this year (presumeably in rackspaces london facility as well)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at OVH, while not strictly "VPS" their RPS service is really good, and you get your own physical hardware. I've used one for a few months and i've never had a serious issue with them.

Remember, with a RPS you'll be sharing that 100mbit connection with your disk I/O to the SAN.

Comment: +1 Cool service - cheaper than both VPS and dedicated and probably 'enough' for more than most people.

Answer (score 1):

We have VPS test machines with HostEurope and Server4You. Technically both are fine, but the service is better at HostEurope.

Another good one is 1&1 (they are actually a German company).